# Query Complexity Too Much For Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I attempting to execute the following query in Access but it seems to be overwhelming the application.

```
 SELECT GPPOutput.PartPrefix, GPPOutput.PartBase, GPPOutput.PartSuffix
 FROM GPPOutput LEFT JOIN PAFBPOutput 
   ON GPPOutput.PartBase LIKE '*' & PAFBPOutput.[TRUE BPNO] & '*';
```

It won't execute without timing out. This is bizarre to me because the following is true about the tables involved in the query:

Roughly 40,000 - 60,000 records between them, each with 9 columns, all data type of text.

This wouldn't appear to me to be too large of a task for Access to handle in a timely fashion.

Comment: don't you have a Cartesian join going on there?

Comment: Yes, I do, unfortunately. But I still don't think it should kill the query.

Comment: 50 000 ^ 2 = 2 500 000 000. That is a lot. From the point of view of the DB engine, your JOIN criteria *sucks*.